# Connect to Linux Mint 16 inbuilt desktop sharing (cinnamon) from Windows 7

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

How do I easily connect to the inbuilt remote desktop sharing in Linux Mint 16 (running cinnamon).

I want to connect from windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows to Linux Remote Desktop](http://superuser.com/questions/281794/windows-to-linux-remote-desktop)

Comment: @MatthewWilliams this is specifically for cinnamon

Comment: Doesn't matter. The answer you get will be the same. Some combination of VNC clients.