# Remote Linux in Windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, remote-desktop, remote, debian-jessie

I have Windows7 on a work and Debian Jessie at home.

I need to start some programs and work in Linux.

I heard about SSH-connections

I want to be able to work through the internet on my computer. (Like VirtualBox)

Are there a fast free solutions? If no, what I have to do?

**What shall I do to work in Linux in my home through the Internet?**

I have all permissions both at home and at work.

Comment: [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/download/linux/) comes to mind.

Comment: I would second TeamViewer, I use it all the time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows to Linux Remote Desktop](http://superuser.com/questions/281794/windows-to-linux-remote-desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a Linux instance inside [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), and use that to get X Windows access via SSH (assuming you enable X in SSH on your home Jessie system). To install and enable SSH with X windows on Jessie, do:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh openssh-server
```

Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Uncomment the following lines:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

Then restart sshd.

```
service ssh restart
```

For a more lightweight solution, you can run an free SSH client such as [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/) on your Windows system, to get command-line access to your home Jessie system. You will still need to install the openssh-server package, but you won't need to enable X over SSH.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the question is that you would like to interact with your Linux machine from a Win7 machine at your office - I had Debian Jessie on my PC on campus and I had Windows 7 at home and windows 10 on my laptop. I used TeamViewer which allowed me to have remote-desktop access and essentially interact with either PC as if I was right there in front of it.

Teamviewer is free if you use it in your personal capacity and does not require that great of an internet connection either, my home line only had 1Mbps.

[This is the link for Linux, scroll down for Debian/pre-multiarch if that applies](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/download/linux/)

If you run into any issues use this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/363083/440769) - solved all my issues when I installed it on Debian.

Comment: If you want to launch teamviewer remotely via SSH:
http://www.tonisoto.com/2013/07/launching-teamviewer-remotely-throught-ssh/